# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, subprocess, data-science, kaggle

Getting issue for the following code.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns  # visualization tool



from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

it is form kaggle.com data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners

Comment: what is the issue.?

Comment: are you running this code on your local machine?

Comment: yes, it is running on local machine, using jupyter notebook

Comment: Please, *do not* put code or error traces in the comments - they are literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead!

Comment: Problem : I'm trying to print list of files in a directory. using subprocess.check_output. when i'm using that method, I'm getting error like "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'.

Comment: can you tell the result of `check_output(["ls", "../input"])`?

Comment: Why not just use `os.listdir('../input')`?

Comment: @user3079474,  Code is copied form the following URL. https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners/

expected o/p: 
combats.csv
pokemon.csv
tests.csv

Comment: Sagar that was evident from the link you mentioned. Can you tell the result of running the codes mentioned by @caseWestern and me.